# Still confused about GPG keys and subkeys

Tags: command-line, encryption, gnupg

I just generated a new key with

> gpg --quick-generate-key

Now, when I do

> gpg --list-keys itz@no-use.mooo.com

I get something like this:

```
pub   rsa2048 2020-01-29 [SC] [expires: 2022-01-28]
      DEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEF
uid           [ultimate] itz@no-use.mooo.com
sub   rsa2048 2020-01-29 [E]
```

but when I do this:

> gpg --edit-key itz@no-use.mooo.com

I get something like the following:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.17; Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Secret key is available.

sec  rsa2048/DEADBEEFDEADBEEF
     created: 2020-01-29  expires: 2022-01-28  usage: SC  
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  rsa2048/BEEFDEADBEEFDEAD
     created: 2020-01-29  expires: never       usage: E   
[ultimate] (1). itz@no-use.mooo.com
```

I thought I understood the concept of keys and subkeys at least somewhat, but this still makes no sense to me.

1. Why does the output show public keys in one case and secret keys in the other case?
2. How come a public key (`pub`) is shown as capable of signing (`S`) in the first case, and a secret key (`ssb`) is shown as capable of encryption (`E`) in the second case?  Doesn't this run counter to what we learned in Public Key Crypto 101?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the output show public keys in one case and secret keys in the other case?

In GnuPG 2.1+, I would guess the `--edit-key` command shows secret keys because that's what it has always done.

Back in GnuPG 1.x (and similarly in the original PGP 2.x), there were two fully separate keyrings (pubring and secring). Some operations worked with one and some worked with the other. So `--list-secret-keys` used to be exactly like `--list-keys` except it read from a different file, and `--edit-keys` used to have a subcommand that would flip between the two views.

> How come a public key (pub) is shown as capable of signing (S) in the first case, and a secret key (ssb) is shown as capable of encryption (E) in the second case? Doesn't this run counter to what we learned in Public Key Crypto 101?

No. The output describes a 'key' as in the PGP object – not a 'key' in the pure cryptographical sense – and the usage flags describe what PGP operations it is *meant* to be used for, not only what crypto operations the "inner" key is mathematically capable of. This means they don't change depending on whether you're looking at the public or private half.

For example, your example PGP keyblock has two RSA keypairs in it, and both of them technically could sign/verify as well as encrypt/decrypt. But the whole point of having two is that you want to keep their purposes separate – i.e. you don't want GnuPG to perform encryption using a subkey meant for signing, so the usage flags filter it out.

(There is no separate flag for "decrypt" or "verify" because the message or signature already indicates which key to use for that.)

This also means there can be multiple usage flags which map down to the same operation (signing or verifying) but in different contexts:

- "S" allows the key to be used for signing messages and files (email, etc.);
- "C" allows the key to be used for signing (certifying) other keys/subkeys;
- "A" allows the key to be used for signing authentication challenges (as in TLS or SSHv2).

Even though all three make the same kind of digital signatures in the crypto sense, the keys themselves are often separate for policy reasons. (For example, the 'c'ertifying key should be much more strongly protected than the 'a'uthentication key.)

Comment: > In GnuPG 2.1+, I would guess the --edit-key command shows secret keys because > that's what it has always done.   -- Well, would you say this is a *good* reason?  And a good user interface?

Comment: BTW, I tried typing "toggle" at the edit-key prompt, with the current version of gpg (2.2).  It accepts that as a valid command but doesn't do anything - keeps showing the secret key and secret subkey.  wth?

Comment: And [this tutorial](https://fedoramagazine.org/gpg-key-management-part-2/) shows that even gpg2 prior to some point (maybe 2.1 as you say) was consistent.  So it was intentionally changed - perhaps to make it more confusing?

Comment: They changed the secret key storage in 2.1 from duplicating everything into a 'secring' to using a format shared between gpg/gpgsm/ssh, and the 'toggle' command stopped being meaningful because there are no longer two keyrings anymore. As the manual outright says, they left the command in so that old scripts using it wouldn't break. Do you actually care whether _I_ think it's a good reason and a good user interface? I am not a GnuPG developer and not responsible for their decisions or lack thereof.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation; I did overlook the part about "toggle" in the manual.  But,as you probably suspect, I still think the interface is terrible.